# get a unique count of events in a column - python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

So I have a dataframe consisting of machine operational time. It contains the date, time and the state (On/Off) of the machine. I want to figure out the unique times the machine was on and record the duration of time it was on.

Sample data:

| Date | Time | State |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | 11:12:12.567 | Off |
| 01/01/2022 | 11:22:12.567 | Off |
| 01/01/2022 | 11:32:12.567 | Off |
| 01/01/2022 | 11:42:12.567 | On |
| 01/01/2022 | 11:52:12.567 | On |
| 01/01/2022 | 12:02:12.567 | Off |
| 01/01/2022 | 12:12:12.567 | Off |
| 01/01/2022 | 12:22:12.567 | On |
| 01/01/2022 | 12:32:12.567 | On |
| 01/01/2022 | 12:42:12.567 | On |
| 01/01/2022 | 12:52:12.567 | Off |

So for the above, we can see that the machine was on 2 unique times. With time durations of ([11:32 - 12:02], [12:22- 12:52])

Comment: What have you tried to do so far?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Shouldn't it be ([11:42 - 12:02], [12:22- 12:52])?